# Не отображается VideoView во фрагменте

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, videoview

Фрагмент имеет следующую разметку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llPage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRecipeName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Длииииииииинное название рецепта"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#eaeaea"/>

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/vvVideoRecipe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_time" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Время приготовления: n минут"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivServings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_servings" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvServings"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Количество порций: 10"
            android:textColor="#000000" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescriptionTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Описание"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#eaeaea"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDesciption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Описание рецепта"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvIngredientsTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Ингредиенты"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#eaeaea" />

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableIngredients"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStepsTitle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:text="Шаги приготовления"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:background="#eaeaea"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableSteps"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TableLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSource"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="Источник:"
        android:textColor="#827E79" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Проблема в том, что не отображается VideoView, если не задать его высоту в dp. Как исправить разметку, чтобы VideoView корректно отображался на экране?

Comment: програмно задавайте ему высоту, либо укажите здесь

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych вы имеете ввиду указывать в dp?

Comment: dp, px, не имеет значения.

Comment: @AndriyMartsinkevych а нет способа установить размер по содержимому? К слову, если на место VideoView поставить ImageView, то он отобразится корректно